# Edit Rejected - should incorrect statements be edited?

Tags: discussion, editing

I proposed an edit for the following answer on the grounds that the TLDR; was incorrect.

[isNotBlank(inputString) vs isNotEmpty(inputString)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222204/isnotblankinputstring-vs-isnotemptyinputstring/222206#222206)

Original statement in answer:

```
TL;DR - If you want to return true when the input is null, use isNotBlank. 
If you want this value to return false instead, use isNotEmpty.
```

Here is my edit comment - The original 'TLDR' to this post states that the difference between isNotEmpty and isNotBlank are their treatment of the null value. This is not correct, and actually contradicts the body of the answer - both of these functions return false when passed null, the difference comes with whitespace.

My proposed edit:

```
TL;DR - If you want to return false when the input is whitespace, use isNotBlank. 
If you want this value to return true instead, use isNotEmpty.
```

Edit rejected.

Reason 1:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I don't think the statement is correct - when the input is null, isNotBlank() returns false. So, I can't see how the edit could possibly deviate from the goal of the post's original writer? The TLDR; contradicts the body of the answer.

Reason 2:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.'

There are already multiple comments pointing out the mistake in the answer, and an alternative answer from several years ago. However, the highest voted and accepted answer still has this (seemingly) incorrect statement within it. I don't see why it 'makes no sense as an edit'. The answer is otherwise good.

My personal feeling is that if there is a minor factually incorrect statement in the answer (in this case the TLDR; is wrong but answer body is correct), and especially if the answer is old and has comments pointing out error which has not been addressed, it should be edited.

Also, the original writer obviously thought that this question was borderline in terms of being valuable - they may have more interesting tasks to get on with on salesforce stack exchange, or may not be interested in engaging with the question - it seems reasonable to me that someone else should edit in this case.

Comment: Both of the statements are not correct in my opinion first one is wrong and your one is incomplete. I see your edit is partially true it would make more sense when you add something like this in the beginning. `Both of the functions return false when the string is null and empty('') but...`